How could I use links to set a JavaScript variable in the destination page?
I'm building a site with many pages containing the same type of content in the same areas. Rather than copy and paste a bunch of html pages, I created just one, mod.html. I use a script to replace each area on the page with the appropriate image or text based on an universal_id variable. Currently, changing the variable in the code changes the contents of the page.
I'd like to be able to create links on my navigation page nav.html, that can open mod.html and change the universal_id variable. I just don't know how to do this. I know pages often add stuff to the end of the url that can be used later, but I don't know how to implement it.
Thinking of getting universal_id by splitting window.location.href, I tried just adding another / followed by the intended id at the end of the link, but that of course messes up the file location.
A quick note: I'd prefer to only use vanilla HTML/JS, and I'm not using any servers or anything, just local html files.

What type is this variable? A string, a number, a boolean, ...? Does the variable change? Is it constant? What's it's favorite color?

I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but you should look into using a "static site generators" (google it) instead of using your own JS for this.

I think you can use some sort of storage logic. If you are transitioning on the same page you can use the locale storage to save the value and retrieve it on the DOM load:
localStorage.setItem("universal_id", ValueOfTheId);
localStorage.getItem("universal_id");

